# vector initialization in constructor

Tags: c++, vector

Is it necessary to initialize ;

```
- vector<string>
- vector<string*>
```

in constructor ?

Comment: better use the reference counting smart pointer instead of  *

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Default initialization will be fine.

For `vector<string *>` you will however need a destructor, a copy constructor and an assignment operator in order to properly delete/copy the `string *` elements in your `vector<string *>` member variable.